# Locust performs very poorly on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, locust

I have a set of Locust tests that I'm using to test a REST API.

These Locust tests perform extremely poorly when running on EC2 instances.

I developed the tests within a Vagrant VM environment using one VM as the Locust master and one VM as the Locust slave.

Without any effort to tweak the tests my Vagrant dev environment can run up 200 users and generate 50 rps.

But if I run the exact same Locust tests on EC2 and hit the exact same API host the performance is terrible.

Example using a C3.large instance as the master and a C3.2xlarge instance as the slave:

If I specify 300 users Locust will generate a 100 or so at the specified spawn rate then only add new users very slowly. It usually slows to the point where it will never actually create 300 users. And at best I get between 5 - 8 rps.

I'm not sure where to start looking for the discrepancy in performance. Is it the Locust master or the slave? Is it something specific to EC2?

Comment: how about the performance ec2, ram and processor?  can't the ec2 send  requests or is it related to performance script?

Comment: The tests run on EC2, just very poorly. I've tried some quite large instances so it's not a RAM or CPU issue. Seems most likely to be Locust related IMO.

Comment: I have run lots of locust tests on EC2 without issue. The slow spawning of user does indicate some kind of resource limitation (not cpu but maybe ports or something related to gevent or whatnot). It would be interesting to see if this is still an issue with a recent locust release, possibly running FastHttpLocust as well.

Answer (score 1):

JusDockin, have you checked the file descriptors limit on your instances?

```
ulimit -n
ulimit -Hn
```

This may directly affect the number of HTTP requests you're able to generate.
I can easily generate 200 users on a t2.small instance (didn't try to generate more, as Amazon doesn't look too kindly at load testing unless you warn them in advance). That's what I have in my user data:

```
echo "*     soft    nofile          40000" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
echo "*     hard    nofile          40000" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```